# how to select the first and last element of a predefined selection in Jquery/Javascript without looping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors, filter

I have a Jquery Mobile [collapsible set](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html), which can have any number of "drawers". JQM assigns corner like this:

```
  collapsibleHeading.find("a").first()
      ...
      .add( ".ui-btn-inner", $el )
         .addClass( "ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom" )
```

I want to add a horizontal-option to the collapsible, so it also works like a tab-box. I have the CSS all ready but the corner **in a single statement** are difficult...

I need to check for direction, which I'm doing like this:

```
 (o.directon) == true/false
```

This is what I have:

```
// predefine classes for HORIZONTAL(first,last,rest) and VERTICAL
baseCorners = o.direction == "horizontal" ? [ "ui-corner-tl", "ui-corner-tr", "" ] : ["ui-corner-top", "ui-corner-top", "ui-corner-top"],
toggleCorners = o.direction == "horizontal" ? [ "ui-corner-bl", "ui-corner-br", "" ] : ["ui-corner-bottom","ui-corner-bottom","ui-corner-bottom" ],
```

So now I can assign **baseCorners** and **toggleCorners** without worrying about direction.

My problem: 
How can I add a check/filter for first/last/remaining collapsibles, so that I can run this in one statement like so:

```
  collapsibleHeading.find("a").first()
      ...
      .add( ".ui-btn-inner", $el )
         .addClass( "if-first" ? baseCorners[0] : "elseif-last" ? baseCorners[1] "else" baseCorners[2] + "same for toggleCorners" )
```

**Question**:
I'm lost... any idea if this is at all possible? Thanks for help.

**EDIT:**
This is what I have now:

```
.filter(":first")
    .add( ".ui-btn-inner", $el )
        .addClass( baseCorners[0] + toggleCorners[0] ).end()
.filter(":last")
    .add( ".ui-btn-inner", $el )
        .addClass( baseCorners[1] + toggleCorners[1] ).end()
.not(':first').not(':last')
        .add( ".ui-btn-inner", $el )
            .addClass( baseCorners[2] + toggleCorners[2] );
```

Not sure this is the most feasable solution though

**SOLUTION:**
Thanks for helping everyone. This is how I did it in then end. Once I had the proposed solution set up, I found out, that JQM runs the script for every element, so I could not use a loop, because on every run, there is only 1 element to loop through.

This way it works:

```
 // if not horizontal, I always assign the same class
 baseCorners = o.direction == "horizontal" ? [ "A", "B", "C" ] : ["D", "D", "D"],
 toggleCorners = o.direction == "horizontal" ? [ "E", "F", "G" ] : ["H","H","H" ],
 // get position of current element and calculate trigger
 collIndex = $('div:jqmData(role="collapsible-set") div:jqmData(role="collapsible") h3').index(collapsibleHeading),
 collTrigg = collIndex == 0 ? 0 : collIndex == $('div:jqmData(role="collapsible-set") div:jqmData(role="collapsible")').length-1 ? 1 : 2;
```

With this setup, the first element always gets index 0, the last always index 1 and everything in between index 2, so I'm staying flexible regarding the number of elements in between.

Then it's just:

```
 $el.add( ".ui-btn-inner", $el )
      .addClass( baseCorners[collTrigg] + toggleCorners[collTrigg] );
```

Nice!

Comment: why do you want it in one statement?

Comment: didn't want to bloat up the code. There must be an easier way than to loop over this again, remove falsely assigned classes and reassign the correct ones.

Comment: so you're saying you need to do something to the first found element, the last found element, and everything in the middle, separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the same. It's not like it's a lot less code, but it avoids repetition and should therefore be easier to maintain.

```
selection.each(function(i,e) {

    var el = $(e),
        index = i===0 ? 0 :
            i===selection.length-1 ? 1 : 
            2;

    el.add( ".ui-btn-inner", $el )
        .addClass( baseCorners[index] + toggleCorners[index] );

});
```

Comment: Actually I think this is jacked up a bit, was basing it on his original soup - i don't think the "add" is needed at all

Comment: @jamietre - the add works, but I can't get first and last to detect. Always goes to index 2

Comment: I'm confused now - what is the purpose of the add? Are all three classes supposed to be added to the one element `.ui-btn-inner`?

Comment: Fixed "first" & "last" - that clearly won't work outside of a single selector :)

Comment: Nope. Jquery Mobile always has a parent and child element, who share classes. This is a pain to select... So you will <a.ui-btn><span.ui-btn-inner></span></a>

Comment: @jamietre: ha. I was doing this too just now :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was about to post a change to frequent's answer, using the "i" variable, but they just updated their answer to do that. So I thought I'd just post an answer based off frequent's original answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/8gYcL/1/

It's definitely not as efficient as checking the "i" variable, but I wanted to show you how you could've used it :)